# jQuery DataTables isn't initializing - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

This was working for me before I started merging in the styling from the designer. FYI, datatables is installed via NuGet along with JQuery and JQueryUI. I am constantly getting the following error in Chrome's dev tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

Here's my code---
In my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Then in the page view:

```
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="ArticlesTable" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Articles)
                    {
                        var pubDate = item.DatePublished;
                        var pubDateShort = pubDate.ToShortDateString();
                        var pubDateDayOfWeek = pubDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                        <tr class="researchArticleContainerTR">
                            <td>
                                <div class="researchArticleContainerDIV">
                                    <div class="researchArticleLeft">image placeholder</div>
                                    <div class="researchArticleRight">
                                        <div class="researchArticleTitle">
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="researchArticleCredits">
                                            By @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.FullName) on @(pubDateDayOfWeek) @(pubDateShort).
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <p class="researchArticleShortDescription">
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <a href="@(Url.Action("Research-Article-Details", new {id = ContentSpecific.SlugifyResearchArticleLinkText(item)}))">Read our full report ></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="researchArticleTRSpacer"></tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // archive list ddl
    $("#ArchiveList").change(function () {
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Archive", "ResearchArticle", new { id = "" })/' + $(this).val(); // get val from ddl
    });
    // setup results as datatable
    $('#ArticlesTable').DataTable(); <-- bombing here ===!!
});
```

JQuery is loaded, but not DataTables...  Now, things have moved around on me a lot merging the design into the logic... maybe something got mixed up. any ideas?

Comment: yes, I see the css/js files referenced correctly like:
<link href="../../Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Most likely jQuery DataTables JS file is not being loaded, check whether `~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js` is a correct path, and check *Network tab* in the *Developer tools* window whether it's actually being loaded and you're not getting `404` error.

Comment: it's loading... just checked Network tab...

Comment: @Beau -- If you type `$.fn.DataTable` in the console - is it `undefined`?

Comment: What version of jQuery DataTables are you using, it should be mentioned in the first line of `jquery.dataTables.min.js`? Method `DataTable()` became available only in DataTables 1.10.

Comment: @tymeJV Yes it is 'undefined' if I type that in console.
Gyrocode.com I'm using 1.10.7

Comment: Are there any other errors in the console? What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: no other errors, 2.1.4. I even tried using the CDN references, but no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.. there was some other JS running after ;datatables; that is for the adobe awesome-font stuff our designer uses. I moved it below the DataTables references and boom, working again.